# Faster implementation of rolling std in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, rolling-computation

For a very large dataframe of say over **50 million rows** what is the fastest way to get rolling standard deviation within a group? I have below implementation which takes ~1 hour. Is there a way to re-frame this problem to get `amount_std` column faster?

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import choices

# Creating large custom DataFrame.
n = int(5*1e7)
unique_n = int(1e6)
unique_ids = list(range(unique_n))
unique_returns = list(np.random.uniform(0,1,unique_n)) + [np.nan]*1000 # adding some NaNs.
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':range(n), 'gby_id':choices(unique_ids, k=n), 'amount':choices(unique_returns, k=n)})
df = df.sort_values('gby_id')

# Adding rolling standard deviation.
print(dt.now()) # Start Time
df = (df.assign(amount_std=df.groupby(['gby_id'], as_index=False)[['amount']].rolling(window=20, min_period=5).std().reset_index(0, drop=True)))
# Forward and back fill NaN values within the group.
df.loc[:, 'amount_std'] = df.groupby('gby_id')['amount_std'].ffill()
df.loc[:, 'amount_std'] = df.groupby('gby_id')['amount_std'].bfill()
print(dt.now())  # End Time
```